# return all possible results from a switch statement

Tags: java

I want to return each adjacent direction based on the step the player inputs. The input can't be char's, they have to be ints (can't just say go south, it has to be steps from the map which I will put down the bottom). Feeling super lost with the nextArea method. 
Please don't write the answer for me just want some guidance.

These are the methods from the GameWorld class

```
/**
 * Returns true if areas s1 and s2 are connected, false otherwise.
 * Also returns false if either area is an invalid area identifier.
 * @param s1 the first area
 * @param s2 the second area
 * @return true if areas are connected, false otherwise
 */
private boolean areasConnected(int s1, int s2) {
    if (Math.min(s1, s2) >= 0 && Math.max(s1, s2) < numAreas) { //valid areas...
        //...but are they connected? 
        return east[s1] == s2 || north[s1] == s2 || west[s1] == s2 || south[s1] == s2;
    }
    //Either s1 or s2 is not a valid area identifier
    return false;
}


/**
 * Determine ID number of an adjacent area given its direction from the
 * current area.
 * @param direction the direction to look (n for north, e for east, s for    south, w for west)
 * @return number of the area in that direction
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if direction is null
 */
    public int nextArea(char direction) {
    int nextIs;    // area number of area in indicated direction

    //Valid values
    final char N = 'n', E = 'e', S = 's', W = 'w';

    trace("nextArea() starts...");

    // examine adjacent areas
    switch (direction) {
        case N: trace("determining number of area to the north");
                nextIs = north[currentArea];
                break;
        case E: trace("determining number of area to the east");
                nextIs = east[currentArea];
                break;
        case S: trace("determining number of area to the south");
                nextIs = south[currentArea];
                break;
        case W: trace("determining number of area to the west");
                nextIs = west[currentArea];
                break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Direction must be one of " + N + ", " + E + ", " + S + " or " + W);
    }

    trace("...nextArea() ends with value for '" + direction + "' of " + nextIs);

    return nextIs;
}
```

my current attempt looks like this in the WereWolfenstein2D class

```
 public void walk(){
    current = gameOne.getCurrentArea(); 

    walk = sc.nextInt();

    // pick a direction to walk into 
    // from that space show connected areas
 }


 public void pickMove(){
 System.out.print("walk shoot, quit or reset?");
 answer = sc.nextLine();
 //walk
 //if area not connected: alert 
 //if into village: alert that they are healed 
 //if containing wolf: altert they are bitten, if already bitten game ends


 switch(answer) {
               case "walk":System.out.print("from " + current + " a direction to walk into south(3), east(1), west(2), north(6),");
                           this.walk();
                           gameOne.tryWalk(walk);
                           gameOne.getCurrentArea();
                        //what I want>>>get current areas to s, e, w and n
```

gameOne.nextArea();

```
                      break;    
               case "shoot": 


                      break;
               case "quit": System.out.print("would you like to start again? (yes/no)"); 
                            restart = sc.nextLine();
                            if (restart.equals("yes")) {
                              gameOne.reset();
                            }
                            else {
                              System.out.println("Thanks for playing");   
                            }
                     break;

               case "reset": //gameOne.reset(); 
                             this.pickDifficulity();
                       break;
                            }
```

}

this is the method from the GameWorld class which has the map

```
//This map is _deliberately_ confusing, although it actually a regular layout
private int[] east =  {1,2,0,4,5,3,7,8,6}; // areas to east of current location (index)
private int[] west =  {2,0,1,5,3,4,8,6,7}; // areas to west of current location (index)
private int[] north = {6,7,8,0,1,2,3,4,5}; // areas to north of current location (index)
private int[] south = {3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2}; // areas to south of current location (index)
private int numAreas = south.length;     // number of areas in the "world"
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem in a bit more detail? Do you mean that the input is the set of 'locations' which are indices in the arrays and you need to return the directions that have to be taken to take each of the steps?

Comment: The input is the location the person wants to head into. The return should state which area numbers surround that according to the location array (or map).

Comment: The input is the location the person wants to head into. The return should state which area numbers surround that according to the location array (or map).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, then you are asking how to change a list of indices (representing positions) into the steps that have to be taken to get to those positions.

You've asked for hints rather than code so I'll give some general pointers and you can let me know if you want more detail.

I think you'll find your solution to be more readable and clear if you convert your directions to an `enum`. That way all code associated with any direction is inside that enum and you can avoid `switch` statements elsewhere.

For example:

```
public enum Direction {
    N(north), S(south), E(east), W(west);

    private final int[] locations;
    Direction(int[] locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }

    public int next(int current) {
        return locations[current];
    }
}
```

You can get a direction from a name using `Direction.valueOf(dir.toUpper())` and then get the next location in a direction using `dir.next(current)`.

Your comment states that you need to go in the opposite direction: take a position and return the positions that lead to that position. This requires iteration: you need to search for that position in your arrays. Again this could be a method in the enum. Here's an example:

```
public int previous(int current) {
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if (locations[i] == current)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So then the position that heads north to 3 is `N.previous(3)`.

To get all possible previous locations I would recommend returning a map from location to direction (interpreted as go from that location in that direciton to get to the current location).

```
Map<Integer,Direction> allPrevious(int location) {
    Map<Integer,Direction> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Direction dir: Direction.values()) {
        int prev = dir.previous(location);
        if (prev >= 0)
            map.put(prev, dir);
    }
}
```

Once you have that map you can easily get all previous positions (`map.keySet()`) and the direction to follow from a given location (`map.get(location)`).